# How often should a sitemap be rebuilt?

Tags: sitemap

How often should a sitemap be rebuilt?  Weekly, monthly?  I'm curious about adding a dynamic sitemap thats generated weekly.  Is that too often?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The purpose of sitemaps is to tell the search engines about the pages in your website that you want them to crawl and index. If new pages are added to your site that you want crawled and indexed then they should be added to your sitemap. If this is occurring daily then you can add them daily. If this is occurring weekly then you can add them weekly. Search engines don't care how often your sitemap changes. They will check it periodically and work with whatever content it may have.